# A JavaScript function to update multiple hidden fields depending if they exist or not

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a JavaScript function which I use to update hidden from fields with the file name of an image shown to a user. This works fine on a page with a single image and single hidden field. I am trying to customize it so that it can be used on a single page to update multiple hidden fields depending on whether they exist or not.

[Previously I tried to call separate functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057063/using-javascript-to-update-hidden-form-fields-with-an-image-file-name-on-seperat) from my `onload` separated by a semi-colon. It would work for the first page/hidden field, but it kept trowing an error when the first hidden field was not available on the second page.

In this attempt I am trying to use a single function with if statements linked to the id of the hidden field but unfortunately I cant seem to get it to work on any of the pages / hidden fields

Can anyone tell my where I am going wrong? I believe it is possible to do this but I am not getting any results. Thanks

**Current Output**

```
<input id="id_9-slider_one_image" name="9-slider_one_image" type="hidden" />
<input id="id_10-slider_two_image" name="10-slider_two_image" type="hidden" />
<input id="id_11-slider_three_image" name="11-slider_three_image" type="hidden" />
```

**Desired Output**

```
<input id="id_9-slider_one_image" name="9-slider_one_image" type="hidden" value="P1DP.jpg"/>
<input id="id_10-slider_two_image" name="10-slider_two_image" type="hidden" value="P6D6.jpg"/>
<input id="id_11-slider_three_image" name="11-slider_three_image" type="hidden" value="P3D3.jpg"/>
```

**My Code**

```
<div class="image_rating">      
    <img src="{% static "survey/images/pathone/" %}{{display_image}}" value="{{display_image}}" onload="updateInput(this)"/>                                                                                   
</div>  



<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateInput(ish) {
    var valueAttribute = ish.getAttribute("value");


    if($(this).attr("id") == "id_9-slider_one_image")
        document.getElementById("id_9-slider_one_image").setAttribute(
        "value", valueAttribute);

    if($(this).attr("id") == "id_10-slider_two_image")
        document.getElementById("id_10-slider_two_image").setAttribute(
        "value", valueAttribute);


    if($(this).attr("id") == "id_11-slider_three_image")
        document.getElementById("id_11-slider_three_image").setAttribute(
        "value", valueAttribute);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: quickest way will be to use a try catch for your action ...

Comment: After lookin on image **src** and **value** attribute. It looks `{{display_image}}` has image extension with it that you are not counting for in you **if** condition while you do comparision

Comment: It's unclear what $(this) refers to in your function. There seems to be a link missing between your image element and the hidden fields. When are these hidden fields created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to this question and [the highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6052884/1214163) I was able to check if the id exists in the page before trying to set the value

```
{% if wizard.steps.current in steps %}              


<div class="image_rating">      
    <img src="{% static "survey/images/pathone/" %}{{display_image}}" value="{{display_image}}" onload="updateInput(this)"/>                                                                                    
</div>  


<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateInput(ish) {
    var valueAttribute = ish.getAttribute("value");

    if (document.getElementById('id_9-slider_one_image')) {
        document.getElementById("id_9-slider_one_image").setAttribute(
        "value", valueAttribute)
    }

    if (document.getElementById('id_10-slider_two_image')) {
        document.getElementById("id_10-slider_two_image").setAttribute(
        "value", valueAttribute)
    }

    if (document.getElementById('id_11-slider_three_image')) {
        document.getElementById("id_11-slider_three_image").setAttribute(
        "value", valueAttribute)
    }

</script>
```